# I can't see the point of this two lines of code

Tags: java

```
public class BruteForceSearch {


    private char[] Text;
    private char[] MyWord;
    private int TextLength;
    private int MyWordLength;


    //word or -1 if not found 
    public int search(String Text, String MyWord) {

        //chars
        this.Text = Text.toCharArray();
        this.MyWord = MyWord.toCharArray();
        this.TextLength = Text.length();
        this.MyWordLength = MyWord.length();


        for (int TextCounter = 0; TextCounter < TextLength - MyWordLength; TextCounter++) {


            int WordCounter = 0;

           //matched increament WordCounter
            while (WordCounter < MyWordLength && this.Text[TextCounter + WordCounter] == this.MyWord[WordCounter]) {
                WordCounter++;
            }

            if (WordCounter == MyWordLength) {
                return TextCounter;
            }

        }
        // return -1 in case you didn't find the word
        return -1;
    }
```

here comes my question what is the point of these loops 
why the start and end like that
the for loop `(TextCounter < TextLength - MyWordLengt)`
the while loop (`while (WordCounter < MyWordLength && this.Text[TextCounter + WordCounter] == this.MyWord[WordCounter]`)

Comment: Are you asking what a for-loop is? I don't see what you are confused about.

Comment: i'm sorry about my stupid question but i think people will help me althoughmy stupidity :D  but i'm asking about the logic not the way that for loop working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is:
Textcounter starts looking at the the array containing the whole text, and for each characater of the text, which are stored in the array Text[], looks for the next letters, and checks if they match the same sequence of letters of the array MyWord[], which contains the word, and if every char match, then it returns the position in the text where the matching word is

The only problem is that the world i'm looking for is for example (champ), if in the text there is a word (championship) it will say that they match, but it should say they don't

Comment: why he did that( TextLength - MyWordLength) although if he let it text length it will work

Comment: another thing about subtracting MyWordLength from TextLength  suppose we have TextLength  of 10 and MyWordLength of 5 the for loop will start from 0 to 4 and don't complete the whole text but the weirdest thing this does work :D

Comment: Ahah,
Because if your word is of length 5 and is inside a text of length 10 the for loop goes till 10 - 5, which means till position 4 like you have said,
But then you have this line of code
WordCounter < MyWordLength && this.Text[TextCounter + WordCounter]
And thanks to this you go from that position 4 till position 9 (because an array of size 10 goes from position 0 to 9)